# FFMPEG crop boundaries animation

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to make crop filter params depends on current time.

Now I have 2 videos - white and aqua squares in one split output video, and this code works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i out/i1.mp4 -i out/i2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[left];[1:v]crop=iw/2:ih:ow:0[right];[left][right]hstack" out/generated.mp4
```

My question is - how to make the border between two videos floating, animated? For example from left side of output vide to the right?

I already tried to use **t** param, e.g. like this:

```
ffmpeg -i out/i1.mp4 -i out/i2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/2+t:ih:0:0[left];[1:v]crop=iw/2-t:ih:ow:0[right];[left][right]hstack" out/generated.mp4
```

But it throws an error:

```
[Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x7fa46060eec0] Error when evaluating the expression 'iw/2+t'

[Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x7fa46060eec0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_crop_0

Error reinitializing filters!

Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument

Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

Can anybody help me to solve this? Or explain - why it isn't possible?

Comment: @llogan smth like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOqhqdBXqR4
I have to make central strip (imaginable border between two videos) movable. And I think, that at t=0 I have to reduce left video size and increase right video. At the t=max point I have to reduce right and increase left.

Comment: @llogan for the beginning constant speed is enough, I just want to understand how to use or debug t-param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the crop filter `w` and `h` can't be animated: only `x` and `y` can be.

Use the [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) filter for a simple solution:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=wiperight:duration=2:offset=5" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps me. Will try to do more complex things with this filter.

Comment: @VlFedotov Did you manage it? I want to be able to set the x and y of the cropping area over time, is that possible?